# SQL Dynamic Columns to Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting-services, crystal-reports

I have the following result set from a certain stored procedure.

```
Tag  | Name  | Color  |   Qty   |     Sizes
 A     Joey    Black    1,2,3,4    S, M, L, XL
 A     Joey    Indigo   5,4,3,2    S, M, L, XL
```

The expected output to crystal report view.

```
                       S   M   L   XL
A   Joey    Black      1   2   3   4 
A   Joey    Indigo     5   4   3   2
```

First, I tried separating the comma separated strings using SQL and managed to convert it to table rows.

```
S
M
L
XL
```

My initial approach was to create separate result sets and construct the report using these blocks of data. Eventually, the separate blocks of data yielded results in multiple sub reports and I am having difficulties combining details from columns as well as rows.

Is there a way to create a report directly from a datatable? I was hoping to modify the SQL Result using .net DataTables and bind it directly to the report. Or maybe there is a much better approach in accomplishing this report?

Any help/idea will be very much appreciated.

PS: Please note that the Sizes are dynamic data and can vary for every record. Also, Qty is directly related to size. i.e Qty 1 = Size S

Comment: If size can vary for every record, why would you use it as a column header in the expected results? Or does it vary for Tag?

Comment: That's how the requirement is, unfortunately. I'm having a hard time figuring this out. I also tried RDLC instead of CR, but it doesn't allow me to put multiple datasets on a single table, though CR does.Yes, it varies for every tag.

Comment: Will you need the totals of the sizes at the end of your grouping?

Comment: Yes, the totals of sizes and overall are a required too.

Comment: ok one more question ... Are there always 4 categories of sizes?

Comment: There can be less or more but never without Qty(could be 0 though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see several ways to approach this in Crystal but give this a try. Rather tedious but should work.
create a formula called 
sz1Hdr

```
if ubound(Split({@Sizes},",")) > 1 then Split({@Sizes},",")[1]
```

repeat that for the maximum number of sizes you might have incrementing the number 1 in both the name of the formula and the content of the formula. so the next one would be sz2Hdr

```
if ubound(Split({@Sizes},",")) > 2 then Split({@Sizes},",")[2]
```

Place those in the header of the group you would create for Tag.

Now create a formula called qty1

```
if ubound(Split({@QTY},",")) > 1 then tonumber(Split({@QTY},",")[1])
```

Create one of those for each of the sz#Hdr formulas you made above incrementing the 1 as well. Place each of these in the detail section below its corresponding header.
Right click each qty# Formula on the canvas and select format field - common and click the X-2 to the right of Suppress and enter this formula in each.

```
CurrentFieldValue=0
```

You can now sum each of those fields to your group footers and/or report footers... Not the cleanest solution but if I understand your requirements this should work.

Comment: I tried this solution and it's working fine except from where the last element of the array not displaying for both Sizes and Qty. And I had to omit the `CurrentFieldValue=0` formula because I somehow need the 0 value.

Comment: I solved the issue of the array by concatenating an additional `,` to the Sizes and Qty result set from sql. Thanks for the help!